# Stored procedure error .. Inserting columns from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure in which i am trying to insert two columns in a table, value of one column is from another table and the value of second column is constant and passed in the parameter.

I think i will have to use a loop of somekind but I have no idea how. Kindly help

**MY stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MTS_MTS_MemberTracking_request
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@monthYear datetime 
AS

select [MemberId] from [dbo].[MTS_Members] where Is_Active='true'

insert into [dbo].[MTS_MemberTracking] (MemberId,MonthYear)values ((select [MemberId]
 from [dbo].[MTS_Members]
 where Is_Active='true'),@monthYear)
```

**Error**

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there can be more than one record in `MTS_Members` having `Is_Active='true'` you can't insert it using `insert... values` syntax.

If you really want to insert IDs of all "active" records then just change your query to:

```
insert into [dbo].[MTS_MemberTracking] (MemberId,MonthYear)
select [MemberId], @monthYear
 from [dbo].[MTS_Members]
 where Is_Active='true'
```

or, if it should be exactly one record to insert - you have to change `where` condition of your select to return exactly one MemberId, store that ID in some variable and use in `insert... values` construction.

Comment: This works but no row is being inserted in to the mts_member_tracking table

Comment: Are you sure you have `where Is_Active='true'` records in `[dbo].[MTS_Members]` table :) If your `Is_Active` column is bit, please mentioned `true` without single quote around it.

Comment: Are you sure select returns something? If `select ...` returns data, then `insert into... select...` have to insert that data into table specified in `insert` clause or throw an error if, for example, there are types mismatch in columns to insert and returned data.

Comment: please use this query to avoid same entry twice `insert into [dbo].[MTS_MemberTracking] (MemberId,MonthYear)
select [MemberId], @monthYear
 from [dbo].[MTS_Members]
 where Is_Active='true' and [MemberId] NOT IN (Select MemberId FROM [dbo].[MTS_MemberTracking] where MonthYear = @monthYear)`

Comment: For example I do not wish to have same rows containing same memberID  and Month year

Comment: @tusharnarang You can use `distinct` keyword to eliminate duplicates. Of, if you're trying to avoid situatiuon when some MemberID is already in target table - use can use select query like `select M.[MemberId], @monthYear from [dbo].[MTS_Members] as M left outer join dbo.MTS_MemberTracking as T on T.MemberID = M.MemberID and T.MonthYear = @monthYear where M.Is_Active='true' and T.MemberID is null`